# Accept something with probability

Tags: algorithms, image-processing

I am reading the following paper https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5e86/db52119d2d691af0365cdba7bb27dc0dc303.pdf and trying to implement the tabu search algorithm they describe for image segmentation. In page 2 of the paper, in step 4 and 6 of the algorithm HTS, they say that if certain conditions are met "then $z_{ij}(t+1)$ with probability" or for example "accept $z(t+1)$ as Tabu image with probability". What exactly does this phrase of "with probability" mean? Can anyone give me some reference to read about this? Where can I find more information about this and how can I implement it in my code? Thanks!

Comment: Those seem to be incomplete sentence fragments -- a bit like reading "She wears a yellow dress" and asking what "wears a yellow" means. Please quote the complete sentence that these statements come from.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I agree with you in that they seem like sentence fragments, but that is how they appear in the paper. This is the reason I am so confused with this algorithm.

Comment: In that case, the statements make no sense.

Comment: We expect references to fulfill the minimal scholarly requirements and be as robust over time as possible. Please take some time to improve your post in this regard. We have collected some advice [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1201/). Thank you!